# Apply custom lut via ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, colorspace

I'd like to batch convert some *log footage* as well as transform each clip into *rec709* colorspace. Is there any way to apply a *custom lut* to the footage? If so, what's the correct way to do that?

Comment: See the [lut3d](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lut3d-1) filter. You can apply colorspace filter afterwards for 709 conversion.

Comment: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may want to use FFMPEG's [lut3d](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#lut3d-1) filter. It requires you to provide a look-up table (a *.cube file). For example, if you have an ARRI camera you can generate these files using [ARRI Color Tool](http://www.arri.com/camera/amira/downloads/) or simply download a package with them from the linked page.

Once you have the files, use FFMPEG like this:

> ffmpeg -i "Input.mov" -vf lut3d="ARRIP3D65PQ108-33.cube" -s 1920x1080
>   -c:v dnxhd -pix_fmt yuv422p -b:v 120M DNxHD_for_Editing.mxf

The important part here is the use of **lut3d** filter:

> -vf lut3d="ARRIP3D65PQ108-33.cube"

where ARRIP3D65PQ108-33.cube is the LUT file to use with the filter.